# Characters changing while exporting to CSV using QGIS

Tags: qgis, encoding, utf-8

I am having an issue where some French characters change to weird symbols when exporting to CSV.  This is after staying accurate through a lot of processing inside of QGIS, while also seemingly inconsistent when it comes to exporting (some layers seem to work while others do not).  When I export to CSV, UTF-8 is the default encoding.

I have a workaround where I can export it to xlsx format and then save to CSV in Excel, but this is not convenient as I will keep running into the problem.  I think I tried using UTF-16 but it also gave weird symbols.

How can I fix this?

Inaccurate output:
[image: Inaccurate output]

Accurate output:
[image: Accurate output]

Comment: Do you open the csv with excel afterwards? Are you sure the actual issue is not excel ignoring the actual encoding? What happens if you open the csv with a texteditor like notepad++?

Comment: Good call, you are correct.  I use Excel to quickly and easily check datasets but I really only edit them in QGIS or python notebooks.  Any idea why Excel does this?  It may even be a setting that I can't change due to using an institutional account (I've encountered this in Word, much to my annoyance).

Comment: You may try something like this: https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-a-csv-file-in-excel about the why I can only tell "because Excel think its smart, but it actually is stupid"... :)

Comment: hah fair enough, they don't call it "artificial" intelligence for no reason

Comment: On the other hand: if all people opening this csv do work at the same institution, you could also save the csv in "System" encoding. This could solve your problem if all instutional accounts do use the same default encoding settings.